# Java LocalDate getting two different results when calling plusDays plusMonths and plusYears

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, localdate

Hello everyone i have code like this

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now().plusYears(1).plusMonths(6).plusDays(5));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now().plusDays(5).plusMonths(6).plusYears(1));
}
```

and i am getting two different results

```
2022-10-31
2022-11-01
```

Can someone explain why ? Thanx

Comment: Try printing the intermediate results.

Comment: It's the difference between the number of days in April compared to May

Answer (score 5):

Because `plusDays` is related to a given month...

Say you are in September, 26th, adding 5 days will give October, 1st.

If you are in August, 26th, leads you to August, 31th.

Arithmetic on dates is not arithmetic on numbers... A month is a month, and is not convertible in a number of days.

See docs about `plusMonths`for example:

> public LocalDate plusMonths(long monthsToAdd)
>
> ...
>
> For example, 2007-03-31 plus one month would result in the invalid date 2007-04-31. Instead of returning an invalid result, the last valid day of the month, 2007-04-30, is selected instead.

That is what is generally expected, adding 1 month to a date will lead you to a date in the following month. But it is not the same for days, you really want to move by a number of days.

Answer (score 1):

Try [printing the intermediate results](https://ideone.com/324nrQ) to help visualize how the operations are applied to the dates in the different orders:

```
// Fix the date, so this is reproducible after today!
LocalDate now = LocalDate.of(2021, 4, 26);
        
System.out.println("First:");
System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(now.plusYears(1));
System.out.println(now.plusYears(1).plusMonths(6));
System.out.println(now.plusYears(1).plusMonths(6).plusDays(5));
        
System.out.println("Second:");
System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(now.plusDays(5));
System.out.println(now.plusDays(5).plusMonths(6));
System.out.println(now.plusDays(5).plusMonths(6).plusYears(1));
```

Output:

```
First:
2021-04-26
2022-04-26
2022-10-26
2022-10-31
Second:
2021-04-26
2021-05-01
2021-11-01
2022-11-01
```

The difference comes because of the different lengths of April and October: 5 days from today, you're in May; 5 days from Oct 26th, you're still in October.

Answer (score 0):

April has 30 days, october 31. If you add the days first you run into the next month, if you add the months first, not:

```
2021-04-26 + 1Year -> 2022-04-26 + 6Month -> 2022-10-26 + 5Days -> 2022-10-31
2021-04-26 + 5Days -> 2021-05-01 + 6Month -> 2021-11-01 + 1Year -> 2022-11-01
```